# How to implement docker image update on edge device not connected to the Internet

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, docker-registry, dockerhub

We need to deploy docker container on edge devices which wont be having Internet. These device occasionally connect to network and one of the device (lets call it H) on the network will have internet access. So, I want to know how we can update docker containers in such scenario. I imagine following two approaches:

1. Create tar of image. Copy it to edge device (say over USB) and then update the image on the edge device.
2. Create local registry on device H. Pull the updated image on this device. Make edge device pull only updated layers from this local registry on H.

**Q1.** Machine H has x86 architecture and edge device is runs arm architecture. Running docker pull command on H wont pull arm image from public docker registry. How can we pull arm image on x86 machine? So that we can follow either of two approaches?

**Q2.** Our docker image tar is of 300 MB and it may grow. So we will require to copy whole 300 MB image tar from device H to edge device. I believe we can create tar only of whole image. Is it, by any chance possible to create tar of only updated layers or reduce the size of tar by any means? (Our image is minimal built by copying only bindaries to scratch docker image)

**Q3.** Is there any other better approach? What is usually followed in the industry?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: you cannot pull images on the x86 machine which aren't x86 compatible, however you can host your local Docker registry to which you can push different arch compatible images. Also you don't have to use Docker client to do it, you can use [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77313463/12445681)).

Q2: doing `docker pull --platform=arm64 nginx:stable-alpine3.17-slim` gave me an image for a different architecture i run on (amd64): `https://paste.debian.net/1312387/` so you can do that

Q3: You can use automation like Ansible to make the deployment faster, so you'd convert each step you do manually to a play which you have to run each time you run an update. You can also use some CI/CD like GitLab CI or Jenkins (there are many options available, I mention them because I know them well) where you'd write a pipeline which does these steps for you. Out of these two the first option sounds more suitable.

Comment: Q2: I guess I can specifiy `--platform=arm64` for `docker pull` command? 
If yes, then can I do: **(1)** Pull from private cloud registry to device H with `docker pull --platform=arm64 my-account/image-name:0.2` **(2)** Rename tag of the pulled image to point it to local registry say `docker rename my-account/image-name:0.2 localhost:5000/image-name:0.2` **(3)** Then `docker push` to push the image to local registry. **(4)** Finally, `docker pull device-H-ip:5000/image-name:0.2` on edge device. Wont this work?

Comment: actually it worked for me:
`docker pull --platform=arm64 nginx:stable-alpine3.17-slim`
https://paste.debian.net/1312387/

Comment: Yes, so the steps I stated in the last comment sounds fine, right? Or is there any improvement or any other better approach to update the container on the edge device in the scenario I explained in question (edge devide dont have Internet, but it is occasionally connected to another device that has Internet)?